# Setting and reading environment variables in Ansible does not work

Tags: ansible, environment-variables

Using Ansible 2.0.0.2 from Ubuntu 16.04

In my playbook I set the following environment variables based on prompt input:

```
---

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  vars_prompt:
    - name: "username"
      prompt: "Specify user"
    - name: "password"
      prompt: "Specify password"

  roles:
    - { role: 'connection' }

  environment:
      OS_HOST: "https://os.host"
      OS_USERNAME: "{{ username }}"
      OS_PASSWORD: "{{ password }}"
```

In the role connection I then try to read and use those env vars with:

```
- name: "connect"
  shell: "client connect {{ lookup('env','OS_USERNAME') }} -p {{ lookup('env','OS_PASSWORD') }} {{ lookup('env','OS_HOST') }}"
```

But it gives the error:

```
"Username: -p", "Password: Login failed (401 Unauthorized)"], "warnings": []}
```

So seems `OS_USERNAME` and `OS_PASSWORD` are neither never set or not read by the lookup (works fine when I login manually with same creds).

So is it a no go to use prompt to set env. vars and read them from ansible?

Comment: Is there a reason you decided to go with environment variables and not "real" Ansible variables?

Comment: I don't own the role so it nothing I can change.

Comment: Read no further than the first sentence under the dup-target.